# It is possible to delete the style inherited?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this site

http://avocat2.dac-proiect.ro/

There you will find a button "about us" ... behind that button is a white background inherited from parent.

I want the background to be transparent.

How can I delete the style inherited from a parent?

This is code HTML:

```
<header id="masthead" class="navbar navbar-default" role="banner">

<div class="container-fluid">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" style="background:transparent !important;font-size:17px;">
      <img src="wp-content/themes/WordPressBootstrap-master/images/DESPRE-NOI.png" class="img-responsive img-center">
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" style="background-color:lavender;font-size:17px;">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
      <p> Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

    <div class="container">
        <nav class="" role="navigation">
<!--            <div class="container-fluid">-->
                <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>




            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-navbar-collapse-1">

                <!--            <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">-->
                <!--                <div class="form-group">-->
                <!--                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">-->
                <!--                </div>-->
                <!--                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>-->
                <!--            </form>-->

                <a class="screen-reader-text skip-link" href="#content"><?php _e( 'Skip to content', 'zdwpbs' ); ?></a>
                <?php
                wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary' ,
                                    'menu_class' => 'nav-menu') );
                ?>
            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
<!--            </div>-->
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </nav>
    </div><!-- .container -->
</header>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant delete css like that. What you can do is override the navbar background to transparent(bootstrap gives a background-color to .navbar-default class.) and add backgrounds to the children.

```
    <header id="masthead" class="navbar navbar-default" role="banner" style="
    background: transparent;
">

<div class="container-fluid">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" style="font-size:17px;">
      <img src="wp-content/themes/WordPressBootstrap-master/images/DESPRE-NOI.png" class="img-responsive center-block">
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" style="background-color:lavender;font-size:17px;">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
      <p> Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

    <div class="container" style="
    background: white;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 30px;
    margin-top: 0px;
">
        <nav class="" role="navigation">
<!--            <div class="container-fluid">-->
                <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>




            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-navbar-collapse-1">

                <!--            <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">-->
                <!--                <div class="form-group">-->
                <!--                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">-->
                <!--                </div>-->
                <!--                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>-->
                <!--            </form>-->

                <a class="screen-reader-text skip-link" href="#content">Skip to content</a>
                <div class="menu-menu-container"><ul id="menu-menu" class="nav-menu"><li id="menu-item-6" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-2 current_page_item menu-item-6"><a href="http://avocat2.dac-proiect.ro/" class="menu-image-title-hide menu-image-hovered"><span class="menu-image-hover-wrapper"><img width="46" height="48" src="http://avocat2.dac-proiect.ro/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/HOME.png" class="menu-image menu-image-title-hide" alt="HOME"><img width="46" height="48" src="http://avocat2.dac-proiect.ro/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/HOME2.png" class="hovered-image menu-image-title-hide" alt="HOME2" style="margin-left: -46px;"></span></a></li>
<li id="menu-item-31" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-31"><a href="http://avocat2.dac-proiect.ro/?page_id=17" class="menu-image-title-hide menu-image-hovered"><span class="menu-image-hover-wrapper"><img width="67" height="48" src="http://avocat2.dac-proiect.ro/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/AVOCATI.png" class="menu-image menu-image-title-hide" alt="AVOCATI"><img width="67" height="48" src="http://avocat2.dac-proiect.ro/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/AVOCATI2.png" class="hovered-image menu-image-title-hide" alt="AVOCATI2" style="margin-left: -67px;"></span></a></li>
<li id="menu-item-29" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-29"><a href="http://avocat2.dac-proiect.ro/?page_id=21" class="menu-image-title-hide menu-image-hovered"><span class="menu-image-hover-wrapper"><img width="60" height="48" src="http://avocat2.dac-proiect.ro/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/CLIENTI.png" class="menu-image menu-image-title-hide" alt="CLIENTI"><img width="60" height="48" src="http://avocat2.dac-proiect.ro/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/CLIENTI2.png" class="hovered-image menu-image-title-hide" alt="CLIENTI2" style="margin-left: -60px;"></span></a></li>
<li id="menu-item-28" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-28"><a href="http://avocat2.dac-proiect.ro/?page_id=23" class="menu-image-title-hide menu-image-hovered"><span class="menu-image-hover-wrapper"><img width="78" height="48" src="http://avocat2.dac-proiect.ro/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/ONORARII.png" class="menu-image menu-image-title-hide" alt="ONORARII"><img width="78" height="48" src="http://avocat2.dac-proiect.ro/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/ONORARII2.png" class="hovered-image menu-image-title-hide" alt="ONORARII2" style="margin-left: -78px;"></span></a></li>
<li id="menu-item-30" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-30"><a href="http://avocat2.dac-proiect.ro/?page_id=19" class="menu-image-title-hide menu-image-hovered"><span class="menu-image-hover-wrapper"><img width="186" height="48" src="http://avocat2.dac-proiect.ro/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/DOMENII-DE-EXPERTIZA.png" class="menu-image menu-image-title-hide" alt="DOMENII-DE-EXPERTIZA"><img width="186" height="48" src="http://avocat2.dac-proiect.ro/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/DOMENII-DE-EXPERTIZA2.png" class="hovered-image menu-image-title-hide" alt="DOMENII-DE-EXPERTIZA2" style="margin-left: -186px;"></span></a></li>
<li id="menu-item-27" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-27"><a href="http://avocat2.dac-proiect.ro/?page_id=25" class="menu-image-title-hide menu-image-hovered"><span class="menu-image-hover-wrapper"><img width="75" height="48" src="http://avocat2.dac-proiect.ro/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/CONTACT.png" class="menu-image menu-image-title-hide" alt="CONTACT"><img width="75" height="48" src="http://avocat2.dac-proiect.ro/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/CONTACT2.png" class="hovered-image menu-image-title-hide" alt="CONTACT2" style="margin-left: -75px;"></span></a></li>
</ul></div>            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
<!--            </div>-->
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </nav>
    </div><!-- .container -->
</header>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could add a CSS class to the About Us element and override the color to :

`{background-color: transparent !important;}`

or you could do it inline by adding :

```
style="background-color: transparent;"
```

to the element directly on the html markup, like so:

```
<div style="background-color: transparent;">Content</div>
```